# How to make 0 not equal to empty string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know the rules that 0 is equal to empty string '' in javascript. So how to make if statement to differ this? I mean, I have field where I insert amount value. For empty string I need one message to show but for 0 value another. Currently, I always catch 0 == ''.

```
    if (amount == '') {
       $("#validation-msg3").addClass("opux-is-visible");

       return false;
    }
    else if (amount < 5) {
        $("#validation-msg1").addClass("opux-is-visible");

        return false;
    }
```

**EDIT.** when I use `===` I do not get condition equals true when field is empty. What does it mean? My amount value is different type than empty string? I parse it like this:

`var amount = parseInput($("#amount").val());`

Comment: `0 == ''` but `0 !== ''`

Comment: use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: But now when I use `===` I do not get condition equals true when field is empty. What does it mean? My amount value is different type than empty string? I parse it like this: `var amount = parseInput($("#amount").val());`

Answer (score 2):

Just use strict compare `===` that will check value AND type of operands.

Comment: thanks but you didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Use three equation signs. It checks the type too and 0 will be different from ''.

```
if (amount === '') {
   $("#validation-msg3").addClass("opux-is-visible");

   return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks but you didn't help